# declining balance methode with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to create declining balance query with mysql to calculate depreciation in accounting

for example equipment cost 16,000, estimated 5 year life, rate 40%. Depreciation

```
Year  book_value_start rate depreciation book_value_end
1          16,000      40%   6,400        9,600
2           9,600      40%   3,840        5,760
3           5,760      40%   2,304        3,456
4           3,456      40%   1,382.40     2,073.60
5           2,073.60   40%     829.44     1,244.16
```

How to create function/query to get result like above? thank you

Comment: Is every year always 40%? Or can different years, equipments, etc, have different depreciation rates?  Exactly what data are you starting with? Just one row for the equipment? Or one row per year? Also, which version of MySQL?

Comment: This isn't really the sort of question you should be asking at this stage, in effect you are asking us to provide an algorithm and code when you should be doing both. We can help you with code if you get into difficulty see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @MatBailie always 40%... for example is an equipment above

Comment: @P.Salmon I hope you can help me with code like function or query table thank you

Comment: You hardly answered anything I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to produce the result you want. For example:

```
with recursive
p as (select 16000.00 as book_value, 0.4 as rate, 5 as total_years),
y (year, book_value_start, rate, depreciation, book_value_end) as (
  select 1, book_value, rate,
    round(rate * book_value, 2),
    book_value - round(rate * book_value, 2)
  from p
 union all
  select
    y.year + 1, y.book_value_end, y.rate,
    round(y.rate * y.book_value_end, 2),
    y.book_value_end - round(y.rate * y.book_value_end, 2)
  from y
  cross join p
  where y.year < p.total_years
)
select * from y order by year
```

Result:

```
 year  book_value_start  rate  depreciation  book_value_end 
 ----- ----------------- ----- ------------- -------------- 
 1     16000.00          0.4   6400.00       9600.00        
 2     9600.00           0.4   3840.00       5760.00        
 3     5760.00           0.4   2304.00       3456.00        
 4     3456.00           0.4   1382.40       2073.60        
 5     2073.60           0.4   829.44        1244.16
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sFPYoGQubiah6PJ7oaG2ga/1).

**Note**: All three parameters are defined in the second line. If you want to change the starting value, rate, or number of years, change it there.

Comment: Just to clarify; this assumes MySQL 8 or above (including MariaDB).

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, I think at this point in time that MySQL 8 was released 4 years ago, and MySQL 5.7 is reaching end of life next year, it's safe to consider version 8 as the default one.

Comment: That it should be. But, alas, many online services continue to provide platforms with 5.7